# Panorama Merging Error

Tags: adobe-lightroom, panorama

I can't create a Panorama in Adobe light room. I keep getting this error: "not enough info to estimate camera motion" as shown in the screenshot

[image: See screenshot]

Comment: What OS and version of Light Room are you using? You might get a better response from [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: https://photographylife.com/how-to-fix-panorama-merging-errors Maybe this will help you to understand more clearly..

Comment: @Burgi I m using Adobe light room cc 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Panorama stitching errors can result in inaccurate merging. Fixing the error in Light room alone won’t help and the files have to be edited using Photoshop or another editor for getting the better result.